# How to Delete Multiple Outlook Appointments at Once

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

I had an Outlook<->Google Calendar sync utility go awry. I now have about an extremely large number invites that start at 1am on mondays in my calendar. I want to delete ALL of them, but there is simply too many to do manually.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this, perhaps with a Macro?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Comment: change the calendar view to `list`. Then... do it like a list.

Comment: @CharlieRB

I've tried to manually delete them. I don't have familiarity with Outlook scripting and Outlook appears to be fairly limited in it's user interface (for example, I can't just right click a day/time slot and select "delete all").

I'm sorry this is less than what you were looking for.

Comment: It's not what *I am looking for* as much as its about how this site works ([ask]). I was trying to help you improve your question with my first comment. Many times questions are posted without any details or even an attempt to resolve it themselves; some even with the expectation someone else will do it for them. Glad you were able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to List View and then you will see all Appointments in one list. You can then shift and/or control click to select and then delete in one go.

Changing to List View differs between versions of Outlook.

Outlook 2010:

1. Select `Calendar` from the Shortcuts list at bottom left
2. Select the `View` tab
3. Click the `Change View` button (located far left by default)
4. Select `List` button from the drop down menu